# Cannot deploy nanoFramework AzureMQTT sample on ESP32

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub, nanoframework

The sample compiles nicely but during deployment I get the error:

```
2020-03-03 08:03:14Z [Found assemblies mismatches when checking for deployment pre-check.] 
2020-03-03 08:03:14Z [Exception occurred during deployment.  
Deploy failed.
*************************************** Couldn't find a valid native assembly required by System.Net.Http v1.2.2.0, checksum 0xAD7C8F88.
This project is referencing System.Net.Http NuGet package requiring
native v. The connected target does not have support for
System.Net.Http. Please check:    1) if the target is running the most
updated image.   2) if the target image was built to include support
for all referenced assemblies.
```

I am using runtime version 1.4.0-preview.120
My assumption was that the installed runtime does not include the required assemblies and I tried to compile my own but ultimately I get the same error.

I am referencing the following NuGet Packages:

```
nanoFramework.CoreLibrary           {1.7.0-alpha.3}                   
AzureMQTT                                                             
nanoFramework.M2Mqtt                {4.4.0-preview.11}                
AzureMQTT                                                             
nanoFramework.Networking.Sntp       {1.4.0-preview.7}                 
AzureMQTT                                                             
nanoFramework.ResourceManager       {1.0.0-preview.5}                 
AzureMQTT                                                             
nanoFramework.Runtime.Events        {1.4.1-preview.5}                 
AzureMQTT                                                             
nanoFramework.Runtime.Native        {1.2.0-preview.8}                 
AzureMQTT                                                             
nanoFramework.System.Collections    {1.0.0-preview.7}                 
AzureMQTT                                                             
nanoFramework.System.Net            {1.4.1-preview.3}                 
AzureMQTT                                                             
nanoFramework.System.Net.Http       {1.2.2-preview.3}                 
AzureMQTT                                                             
nanoFramework.System.Text           {1.0.0-preview.1}                 
AzureMQTT
```

My question is:
Which assemblies do I need for the AzureMQTT Sample?
or If my assumption is wrong where is the problem?

Comment: Can you revert corlib to version 1.6.x (i.e. non alpha) and see if that works...

Comment: Robin - I tried it and it didn't help. Please see my comment to Mateusz

Answer (score 2):

Funfacts: I didn't need nanoFramework.System.Net.Http {1.2.2-preview.3} at all.
Without it and with VS extensions 1.8.0.5 the software deploys.

Thank you,
Richard

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade VS extension to <1.7
Issue with deploying HTTP Nuget is a side effect from the latest improvements in the deploy provider along with the new MDP

Comment: Thank you Mateusz - I downgraded the CoreLibrary but nothing changed. If I downgrade nanoFramework.System.Net.Http he is looking for the matching assembly on the device:
"Couldn't find a valid native assembly required by System.Net.Http v1.1.0.3, checksum 0x36CC0CCA."

Comment: Mateusz is recommending you downgrade the VS extension to 1.6.x, not the corlib.

Answer (score 0):

Know that with the latest version of the VS extension and libraries, you should be able to connect without any issues.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I updated my NuGet and NanoFramework extension and ESP32 WROOM firmware all to the latest version but the error "Found assemblies mismatches when checking for deployment pre-check." is still in existence, :( Although the idea to program micro controllers with C# is so fascinating but support and demos are not doing well.

Comment: @A.R.S.D. you realize that the answer above dates from July 2020. A lot has changed since then.
Moving forward: care to share the device capabilities output along with the full error message you're getting?

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply! I am not trying to deploy this example but the very simple primary "Hello World" sample, on this board. unfortunately the latest native firmware which is on the board is not assembly compatible with the latest CoreLibrary. I tried to downgrade but no success. My last suggestion is to downgrade native firmware but i don't know how to do this although checked every source i found. i think the documentations are insufficient. Thanks for this cool project. I hope as any other innovation these initial problems fade away soon.

Comment: Here is some more details-> Native Firmware: CLR Version: 1.6.1.52, CoreLibrary Version: 1.7.3 which needs mscorlib v100.4.10.0. But native firmware has later version of mscorlib which is mscorlib v100.5.0.5. So as they are both latest version that i was able to download with VS 2019. I suggest the only way is to downgrade native firmware to some compatible one which has lower version of mscorlib. but don't know how. I also tried to update NuGet so to prevent the need for manual configuration in hope that newer version for CoreLibrary

Comment: If you've flashed your ESP32 with a preview fw, you also have to use preview NuGet versions. For that tick the "include prerelease" box in VS Package Manager. That will get you mscorlib 1.10.1-preview.11, which is the one matching the latest preview firmware.
BTW, all this is described in 3. in the getting started guide [here](https://docs.nanoframework.net/content/getting-started-guides/getting-started-managed.html#coding-a-hello-world-application).

Comment: Yes i have read about it, but i don't think that i am using preview version. But thanks i go check it deeper this time.